# docker login to gitlab registry with github account

Tags: docker, gitlab

I've just created a GitLab account with my GitHub account.

How do I sign in to my GitLab registry using my GitHub account?

`docker login` with my GitHub password doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once your GitLab account created, you should be able to create a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/#personal-access-tokens)

```
docker login -u gitlab-token -p gitlab-token registry.gitlab.com
```

As noted in [issue 21309](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21309#note_18992542), when running from GitLAb-CI, that would be

```
docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!